# Curl works but Python request fails

Tags: python-3.x, curl

I've been trying to do a POST request on an api using Python `requests`. The curl command seems to work, but the Python `requests` fails.

The following is the `curl` code:

```sh
curl --location --request POST '{{url}}' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
--header 'Accept: application/json;v=1' \
--header 'Md5-Checksum: {{checksum of file_to_upload}}' \
--header 'Authorization: {{auth-token}}' \
-F 'file=@{{path of file_to_upload}}'
```

The following is the analogous `Python` code:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Accept': 'application/json;v=1',
    'Md5-Checksum': f'{checksum of file_to_upload}',
    'Authorization': f'{auth-token}',
}

files = {
    'file': (f'{path of file_to_upload}', open(f'{path of file_to_upload}', 'rb')),
}

response = requests.post(f'{url}', headers=headers, files=files, verify=False)
```

This however throws the error:

```
{
"actions":[],
"id":"200000",
"text":"Our system experienced an error. Please try again later",
"developerText":"Request validation error",
"errorDetails":[{"id":"200000","text":null,"developerText":"HTTP 400 Bad Request"}]
}
```

Can someone please tell what the difference is in the two ways?

Comment: `data=files` ? Insteaf off `files=files`?

Comment: Didn't work. I also tried `json=files`, but that requires the byte stream to be `json-serializable`, which is not the case as the upload file is a pdf.

Comment: what is the actual error this throws?

Comment: I've updated the question to include the error details.